# Reference on semigroup theory and fractional heat equation

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, semigroups-of-operators

Consider the Dirichlet problem associated to the classical heat equation $\partial_t u - \Delta u = 0$ and to the fractional heat equation  $\partial_t u + (- \Delta)^s u = 0$.

- Where can I find a reference on semigroup theoretic approach to these problems?

> In particular, where can I find a proof that there exists one and only one solution to
>
> $$\partial_t u + (- \Delta)^s u = 0 \;\text{ in } \Omega,\quad t>0$$
>   $$u=0 \;\text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Omega, \quad t>0$$
>   $$u(t,x) = u_0(x) \;\text{ in } \Omega, \quad t=0,$$
>
> which is given by $$u(t,x) = (T(t)u_0)(x), \overline{\Omega}, t \ge 0$$
>   where $(T)_{t \ge 0}$ is a strongly continuous semigroup (on $C$, $BUC$, or $C_b$ or one $L^p$ space) and the solution continuously depends on the initial datum?

Comment: For the Laplacian, this is *very* standard. Recently I wrote a [paper about various definitions of the fractional Laplace operator](https://doi.org/10.1515/fca-2017-0002) ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07356)), with a section on semigroup approach; it does not contain any proof, but it points to some references that might be relevant.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you for your comment. I edited my question to make it more specific.

Comment: Oh, so you mean the Dirichlet problem. Now you need some regularity of $\Omega$ for the existence of the solution, and a maximal principle for uniqueness. You also need to specify in what sense the fractional Laplacian is understood, and in what function space your solutions are. I guess you will find a lot of information [here](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=1435-9855&vol=12&iss=5&rank=9) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2626). For a more general approach, you can consult potential-theoretic literature (e.g. Bliedtner–Hansen book), but this will be a hard read.

Comment: Try "Long-term behavior of reaction-diffusion equations with nonlocal boundary conditions on rough domains" located here among other places  https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05744

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(-\Delta)^s$ instead of $-\Delta^s$ ?